# SmartCardCredentialsProvider.dll UI doesn't accept user input

Tags: winapi, mfc, windows-authentication, windows-security

My company is programming for the SmartCard security setup in Windows.  However, we hit a snag when we updated to Fall Creators, which a developer was able to mitigate by not passing a parent window to the [`CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (desktop/root/`NULL`).  If we pass a parent window, it results in the Smart Card Login dialog to not be accessible, as in the window pops up, but when you click on it, the Window's Default Beep is heard and you cannot type anything.  I've looked using Spy++ and it states that there is no child window that is interfering, but there are messages getting to the window that Spy++ can see (`WM_SETCURSOR`, `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_LBUTTONUP` and a bunch of registered `SHELLHOOK` with various parameters).

The application is written using the MFC MBCS framework if that makes a difference.

Things that I've tried are:

1. Showing the parent window (currently hidden).  This sometimes works when I use `::ShowWindow(m_Parent, SW_SHOW);` but never works when I use `::SetWindowPos(m_Parent, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);`
2. I've attempted to detour the message and thread creation functions in an attempt to log what's going on, but I don't seem to get any information.

I'm really scratching my head on this.  Why would the Smart Card Login window not get the focus?  What could be interfering with this?  We need to stop using this workaround and actually get the Smart Card Login to have a parent window.

Some stuff I found in the Debug Output window are:

```
Exception thrown at 0x763008F2 in app.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: errorlib::specific_error_exception<hresult_error::tag> at memory location 0x3B74F824.
Exception thrown at 0x763008F2 in app.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: errorlib::specific_error_exception<hresult_error::tag> at memory location 0x3B74F824.

Exception thrown at 0x763008F2 in app.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: errorlib::specific_error_exception<hresult_error::tag> at memory location 0x3B74F8E4.
Exception thrown at 0x763008F2 in app.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: errorlib::specific_error_exception<hresult_error::tag> at memory location 0x3B74F8C8.

onecoreuap\ds\security\fido\credprov\dll\fidoscenariocredui.cpp(44)\fidocredprov.dll!3C8CD0D9: (caller: 3C8CB529) ReturnHr(1) tid(5488) 80070057 The parameter is incorrect.
    Msg:[InvalidFlags 32] 
onecoreuap\ds\security\fido\credprov\dll\fidoprovider.cpp(62)\fidocredprov.dll!3C8CB540: (caller: 27886879) ReturnHr(2) tid(5488) 80070057 The parameter is incorrect.

onecore\ds\security\biometrics\credprov\provider_v2\bioprovider.cpp(99)\BioCredProv.dll!3CDC9620: (caller: 27886879) ReturnHr(1) tid(5488) 80098003     CallContext:[\SetUsageScenario] 
onecore\ds\security\biometrics\credprov\provider_v2\bioprovider.cpp(206)\BioCredProv.dll!3CDC9117: (caller: 27886ECF) ReturnHr(2) tid(5488) 80004001 Not implemented
    CallContext:[\UnAdvise] 

onecoreuap\shell\auth\credprov2fahelper\dll\credprov2fahelper.cpp(80)\CredProv2faHelper.dll!2B0F63E5: (caller: 278870A4) ReturnHr(1) tid(5488) 800704EC This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.
    Msg:[Device unlock policy not configured] 
onecore\ds\security\ngc\utils\common\lib\sidutils.cpp(786)\ngccredprov.dll!3CE59F69: (caller: 3CE58CA0) ReturnHr(1) tid(5488) 80070057 The parameter is incorrect.
Exception thrown at 0x763008F2 (KernelBase.dll) in app.exe: 0x0000071A: The remote procedure call was canceled, or if a call time-out was specified, the call timed out.
Exception thrown at 0x763008F2 (KernelBase.dll) in app.exe: 0x0000071A: The remote procedure call was canceled, or if a call time-out was specified, the call timed out.

Exception thrown at 0x763008F2 (KernelBase.dll) in app.exe: 0x0000071A: The remote procedure call was canceled, or if a call time-out was specified, the call timed out.
Exception thrown at 0x763008F2 in app.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: unsigned long at memory location 0x3B74F194.
```

Though these appear when the parent is the root (desktop) or our window, so I'm not sure if they mean anything.

## EDIT

Here is the code (more or less) that is used to bring up the Smart Card dialog:

```
CREDUI_INFOW credUIInfo;
memset(&credUIInfo, 0, sizeof(credUIInfo));
credUIInfo.cbSize = sizeof(credUIInfo);
credUIInfo.hwndParent = m_Parent;
credUIInfo.pszCaptionText = L"Smart Card Login";
ULONG ulAuthPackageID = 0;

HANDLE hLSA = NULL;
DWORD dwErr = LsaNtStatusToWinError(LsaConnectUntrusted(&hLSA));
if (dwErr == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    LSA_STRING lsaszAuthPackageName;
    SizeTToUShort(strlen("Negotiate"), &lsaszAuthPackageName.Length);
    lsaszAuthPackageName.MaximumLength = lsaszAuthPackageName.Length + sizeof(CHAR);
    lsaszAuthPackageName.Buffer = (PCHAR)"Negotiate";

    dwErr = LsaNtStatusToWinError(LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage(hLSA, &lsaszAuthPackageName, &ulAuthPackageID));
}

// Disconnect from the LSA server:
if (hLSA) {LsaDeregisterLogonProcess(hLSA);}

KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON credFilter;
memset(&credFilter, 0, sizeof(credFilter));
credFilter.MessageType = KerbCertificateLogon; // (indicates an interactive smart card certificate login)

LPVOID pCredBuffer = NULL;
DWORD dwCredLen = 0;

dwErr = CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW(&credUIInfo, dwErr, &ulAuthPackageID, &credFilter, sizeof(credFilter), &pCredBuffer, &dwCredLen, NULL, CREDUIWIN_IN_CRED_ONLY);
```

## EDIT 2

It appears that the dialog is disabled according to Spy++.  Writing a quick little app that, given any window handle, will enable the window associated with that handle by calling `EnableWindow()` will actually enable the window.  Why would this be the case?  Why would the window be disabled?

Comment: If you have a normal visible window you pass it's HWND and if not you pass 0, why do you need this strange parent window?

Comment: @Anders, I'm not sure if I understand your question. The patent window is not strange, we just don't want it to be visible. IIRC, it may be in the middle of its creation function, but in any case, it shouldn't cause such odd inconsistent behavior. There's no reason for a dialog to be made visible but not enabled.  It's kinda counter productive.

Comment: A parent window should be visible and enabled, if you don't have such a window then you should pass NULL as the parent.

Comment: @Anders, if that were the case then why is it that when I make it visible, that it works sometimes but not others?

Comment: Another thing @Anders, even if the window is hidden, it still has a higher zorder than others.  I have observed that using the desktop as the parent (via NULL handle) will result in the security window appearing below other windows that are currently on the screen.

Comment: @Adrian Just curious how to validate the credentials unpacked from the BLOB - pCredBuffer?

I have a similar task related to this winAPI

Comment: @ArjunNatarajan, sorry, what are you asking?  You mean check to see if it is the correct credential BLOB?  This was a while ago, but I'd assume that you get the credential BLOB to compare it to from Windows somehow.

Comment: @Adrian I am trying to fetch the credentials of the smartcard using "CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer" & then I need to validate the provided one has administrator privilege in the machine?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to this problem, which I think is better then not setting the parent, is to poll for the security dialog and once it is visible and it is still not enabled, then enable it.

```
constexpr UINT_PTR enable_window_id = 0;
::SetTimer(m_Parent, enable_window_id, 100, [](HWND hwnd, UINT /*msg*/, UINT_PTR id, DWORD /*dwTime*/)
{
    if (HWND hChild = ::FindWindow(_T("Credential Dialog Xaml Host"), nullptr))
    {
        if (::IsWindowVisible(hChild) && !::IsWindowEnabled(hChild))
        {
            ::EnableWindow(hChild, TRUE);
            ::KillTimer(hwnd, id);
        }
    }
});

//...
// CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials(...) call
//...

// If MS ever fixes this problem, will need to kill this timer manually
::KillTimer(m_Parent, enable_window_id);
```

I personally think this is really kludgy, but who knows when MS will fix it.